# How to use a SOCKS 5 proxy with cURL?

Tags: php, curl, proxy, socks

Normal proxies (ex: `72.41.132.22:3128`) work well with cURL, however when I use SOCKS 5 proxies with username/pass, It just gives me "[1" on the page.

Is there a way to use SOCKY 5 proxies with cURL ?

```
$proxy = "cagsan:jw22wdw@108.61.25.223:34792";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to tell cURL the proxy is a SOCKS5 proxy, otherwise cURL assumes it's an HTTP proxy:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
```

From the [docs](http://php.net/curl_setopt):

> **CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE**
>
> > Either CURLPROXY_HTTP (default) or CURLPROXY_SOCKS5.

Comment: As @Gido mentioned you can skip this param and use `CURLOPT_PROXY` with prefix `socks5://` and you're good to go. [docs](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_PROXY.html)

Answer (score 34):

since cURL 7.21.7, you can use `CURLOPT_PROXY` and specify the SOCKS protocol:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'socks5://bob:marley@localhost:12345');
```

More informations in the [libcurl documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTPROXY).

Answer (score 4):

For those looking to connect via a hostname(localhost?), and it's not working with `CURLPROXY_SOCKS5`, you can try `CURLPROXY_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME`.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME);
```

In some earlier PHP versions, you will have to do:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 7);
```

Comment: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_PROXY.html - CURLPROXY_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME indicates that hostname resolution should be performed by socks server.

Comment: my PHP version `PHP 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )` and `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 7);` works to me, thanks