# How to work with proxy-server for parsing data through websocket?

Tags: php, parsing, websocket, proxy

I need to establish a long-term connection to the websocket (wss) of a remote site through a proxy server to receive data from the site.
Tried using this [library](https://github.com/arthurkushman/php-wss) (client), and answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444738/how-to-use-a-socks-5-proxy-with-curl), to no avail.
Is there a way to use a proxy-server to parse data from a remote websocket?